# Clean PathInfo URLs and Query Strings on IIS 5.1 and PHP 5

Tags: php, iis-5, clean-urls

I'm trying to get 'clean' PathInfo style URLs with query string parameters working on PHP 5.3 and IIS 5.1 using FastCGI. I've found that I can use:

(**1**) `http://www.example.com/index.php?/path/to/foo/`

but not:

(**2**) `http://www.example.com/index.php/path/to/foo/` (Note the missing **?**)

Which isn't a big issue until I want to mix URLs with a query string like:

(**3**) `http://www.example.com/index.php?/path/to/foo/?color=blue&size=small`

That makes my $_GET look like:

```
Array
(
    [/myapp/foo/bar?colour] => blue
    [size] => small
)
```

Is there way to get a URL scheme like (4) below to work, and with $_GET being populated correctly on IIS 5.1?

(**4**) `http://www.example.com/index.php/path/to/foo/?color=blue&size=small`

P.S. - I remember being able to do this before, but I suspect I was using Apache at the time and not IIS. Unable to use Apache for this. However the production server has IIS7 (I only have IIS 5.1 on my machine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For (3), you simply need to treat the query-string as a single piece of text. You should not be using `$_GET` - you should be using the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable directly, instead. You should get `/path/to/foo/?color=blue&size=small`.

For (4), you should concatenate the `PATH_INFO` and `QUERY_STRING` environment variables, joined with a `?`, and use that value. Again, you should get `/path/to/foo/?color=blue&size=small`. This is because `PATH_INFO` has `/path/to/foo` and `QUERY_STRING` has `color=blue&size=small`.

Comment: Thanks! This works great. For IIS5, since it requires the 'index.php?' and not simply 'index.php', I also needed to split the on the '?', and then use parse_str on the result.